# $\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x+3}=?$

Tags: limits

**My attempt:**

Let $y=\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x+3}$

Now,

$$\ln y=\ln \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x+3}$$

$$\ln y=(x+3)\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \ln y=\lim_{x\to \infty} (x+3)\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

I'm stuck. What do I do now?

Comment: Why not just write it as $(1+\frac{1}{x})^x(1+\frac{1}{x})^3$?

Comment: The trick is $(x+3)ln(1+\frac{1}{x})=\frac{ln(1+\frac{1}{x})}{\frac{1}{x+3}}$ and then L'Hospital rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \ln y=\lim_{x\to \infty} (x+3)\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

you can write it as

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \ln y=\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\frac{1}{x+3}}$$

which is of the form  $$ \frac{0 }{0}$$

differentiating right side w.r.t. x gives

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \ln y=\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\frac{-1}{x(x+1)}}{\frac{-1}{(x+3)^2}}=1$$

complete from here.

Answer (score 5):

There is an easier way:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x+3}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^3=e$$
since $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x=e$, by definition of euler number and $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^3=1$

Answer (score 5):

Write it as
$$(1+\frac{1}{x})^{x+3} = (1+\frac{1}{x})^{x}(1+\frac{1}{x})^{3}$$
Taking limit yields
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{x})^{x}(1+\frac{1}{x})^{3} = \lim_{x\to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{x})^{x} \cdot 1 = e$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** You have obtained $\infty\times0$. Convert it into $\frac\infty\infty$ form or $\frac00$ and then apply L'Hopital.

If you don't want to use L'Hopital then you can use series expansion for $\log$.

$$\log(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}3-...$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $\ln(1+t)\sim t$ as $t\to0$, we have
$$(x+3)\ln\left(1+\frac 1x\right)\sim\frac{x+3}x\sim 1\qquad \text{as }\ x \to\infty.$$
So $\ln y\to1$ and thus $\lim_{x\to\infty} y=e$.